# How to pre-calculate the total in table cells when he page opens

Tags: javascript

I have created an html table that dynamically calculates the total values of cells when any value is changed.  I would like the 'Total' values to be calculated on page load and not just on change.  I use event listeners to calculate when a change is made.

I have tried using event 'load' but that did not work.  Below is my codepen.

-------------------HTML--------------------------------

```
      <table id="AdvStaffing" border="1" width="100%" height="300px">
                     <tr class="tblHeader">
                                    <td colspan="5">Advisor Staffing</td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr class="subHeader">
                                    <td>Region</td>
                                    <td>Pilot</td>
                                    <td>Name</td>
                                    <td>Trainer</td>
                     </tr>
      </table>
```

------------------JavaScript---------------------------------------------

```
    $(document).ready(function() {                
              var BenAdvStaffing = document.querySelector("#AdvStaffing");
              calculate(BenAdvStaffing,"BenAdvStaffing");        
});



  function getColumnSum(tbl){
     var colSum=0;
     for (var i=0; i<tbl.rows.length; i++)
     {
        colSum = colSum + tbl.rows[i].cells[1].children[0].value;   
      }
     return colSum;
      }

       getData("Advisor Staffing");

             function getData(listName){  
               console.log(listName);
                           var root = 'https://my-json-server.typicode.com/isogunro/dashboard/posts';
               console.log(root);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: root,
                        method: 'GET'
                    }).then(function (data) { 
                      console.log(data);
                          if (listName == 'Advisor Staffing'){
                               buildTable(data,"#AdvStaffing",listName);
                          }
                    });                          


              }  

           function buildTable(data,tblIDName,lstName){    
                          var tblRef = document.querySelector(tblIDName);
                          var tblRow = data.length;
                          for (var x=0; x<data.length; x++){              
                                         var newRow = tblRef.insertRow(-1);                        
                                         if(tblIDName == "#AdvStaffing"){
                                           console.log(tblIDName); 
                                           var cell = newRow.insertCell(0);
                                           cell.innerHTML = "<input type='text' size='7' class='"+getClass(data[x].Region)+" column0' readonly value='"+data[x].Region+"'>";
                                           var cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);                                             
                                           cell2.innerHTML = "<input type='text' size='5'  style='text-align:center' class='"+getClass(data[x].Region)+" column1' data-id='"+data[x].ID+"' data-columnName='Current' style='width:65px' value='"+data[x].Pilot+"'>";
                                                                         var cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2);                                             
                                           cell3.innerHTML = "<input type='text' column2'  size='5' style='text-align:center' class='"+getClass(data[x].Region)+" column2' data-id='"+data[x].ID+"' data-columnName='Deployed' style='width:55px' value='"+data[x].Name+"'>";

                                                        var cell4 = newRow.insertCell(3);                              
                                                                            cell4.innerHTML = "<input type='text' size='5'  style='text-align:center' class='"+getClass(data[x].Region)+" column3' data-id='"+data[x].ID+"' data-columnName='Vacant' style='width:55px' value='"+data[x].Trainer+"'>";
                                         }

                          }
           }
```

I expect the calculations to be there when the page is brought up.

codepen: https://codepen.io/isogunro/pen/BrQXPJ?editors=1011

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** The provided code does not match the code that is currently shown in the provided Codepen. This answer references what is currently in the Codepen (forked here for reference: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/daWOyy?editors=1011).

I see two main issues with your code that are preventing the values from being calculated on page load.

The first is that the `calculate()` method only sets the even listener, but does not actually execute any of the calculation logic (this logic will only be executed when the listener fires). To fix this, I would suggest refactoring you code so that the calculation logic is in it's own method, which is then called from the event listener.

The second issue is that I believe the calculate logic will not work until after `buildTable()` has been called, so rather than calling `calculate()` from the on load handler, call it from the ajax handler in `getData()` instead.

Rough framework of how to implement the above two changes:

```
// This is the same as using $(document).ready(),
// and is recommended in jQuery 3.x
$(function () {    
    /*
    var tbl = ... get table element ...
    */

    // Since you're using jQuery, might as well use jQuery events
    // Also, using a delegate selector will ensure that only changes to input elements are handled
    $(tbl).on("change", "input", function (e) {
        // pass any necessary arguments to calculate()
        calculate();
    });

    // I would recommend calling getData() after page load as well.
    // You have to wait a short time before the AJAX request is sent,
    // but the bonus is you can be sure the document is loaded by the
    // time it returns
    getData("Advisor Staffing");
});

// accept any necessary parameters
function calculate () {
    /*
    ... calculation logic goes here ...
    */
}

function getData () {
    /* Setup and make ajax request with appropriate params */
    $.ajax().then(function (data) {
        // pass any necessary arguments to buildTable()
        buildTable();
        // pass any necessary arguments to calculate()
        calculate();
    });
}
```

**Update:** demonstrate jQuery delegate selector in the above example.

Comment: I made changes according to your suggestions, I think, but it's not calculating anymore.  I believe it's because I'm not sure how to pass the target(e) as a argument.  See lines 6 and 30 in my codepen.  Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Two points:

1) You were using the wrong variable name on line 6, `tbl` is never set, changing it to this will make it work: `$(BenAdvStaffing).on("change", function (e) {`.

2) I would recommend refactoring your calculate method to not need the event object as a parameter. You are actually only using the event object for two things in that method. The first is checking if the target is an input, which can be more easily done with a jQuery delegate like so: `$(BenAdvStaffing).on("change", "input", function (e) {`, the second is selecting the table, which you can instead do by using its id.